# how to add layers and error bar and points in ggplot2 using a for-loop

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am developing an application in R shiny and I would like to make a graph dynamic by adding points, error bar, and lines using the ggplot2 package R.
The columns of my dataframes have no names because I merge Excel files uploaded by the user using R's cbind.data.frame(), so the dataframes depend on how many files the user uploads. This also affects the ggplot.
But I know the number of columns that separate the data I have to use in my dataframe so I created dynamic variables named y, k, and z that increment each time for the choice of the right columns in the respective dataframes.
I found this code and I adapted it to my code but I have the following errors

'''

```
plotAllLayers<-function(df){
    y<-0
    z<-1
    k<-0
    p <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=df[,1], y=df[,2])) + labs(x="deltaExWL (nm)",y="CSM")

    for(i in 1:input$nberspl_one){
      
      p <- p + geom_point(aes(x=df[,1], y= df[,y+2]), color = "blue")+
              geom_errorbar(aes(ymin= df[,y+2] - df[,y+3], ymax= df[,y+2] + df[,y+3] ), color = "blue")+
              geom_line(data=df_fitted, aes(x=df_fitted[,1], y = df_fitted[,k+3]), color = "blue")

      z<- z+1
      y<- y+3
      k<- k+4
    }
    return(p)
  }
  plotAllLayers(Alldfplt)
```

'''

Error in check_required_aesthetics: geom_line requires the following missing aesthetics: y

Error in check_aesthetics: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (57): ymin and ymax

[Alldfplt for 3 files uploaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCx4C.png)

[df_fitted for 3 files uploaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmYU7.png)

I would like to get graphics like this:[image: Final result I would like to get if user uploads 4 files]

if the user uploads 4 files.

Thanks in advance for your help!!!

Comment: Please don't upload code, error messages, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.